# How do I use dictation paste with applescript?

Tags: macos, applescript, voice-dictation

I am trying to make dictation code snippets/templates with applescript because I want to add multi language functionality and toggle between languages to change syntax.

What's the programmatic way of using the built in dictation's paste feature?

Also, is there any command for cursor placement after paste?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If dictation is enabled and running on your system,  the command you would say to paste something from your clipboard is “Paste That”.

If dictation is enabled and running on your system, you can say the command “Show Commands” … which should open a window showing all of your dictation commands

> Also, is there any command for cursor placement after paste?

Look at the "Navigation" section of the image below for cursor placement commands

[image]

Once this window was open you can then say something like. “How Do I Paste”.  This should narrow down the results to all of the dictation commands with the word “Paste”

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even know this commands window existed. I tried to poke around a  bit before asking here, but I couldn't find it. I think I can handle it from here but I will come back here if I have any troubles linking all of this up!